# Why calling a function inside another function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

```
var mult = (function(){
    var cache = {};
    var calculate = function(){
        var a = 1;
        for(var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++){
          a = a * arguments[i];
        }
        return a;
    }

    return function(){
      return calculate(arguments);
    }
})();

console.log(mult(1, 2));
```

Above is my code, I expect the mult function will give me value 2, but instead it outputs NaN. I changed the line `calculate(arguments)` to `caculate.apply(null, arguments)` and it worked. I don't know why the old code doesn't work? Why do I need to use apply in this case? What does `null` represent here?

Comment: Why are you going for this much indirection anyway?

Comment: Why this code is so much complicated?

Comment: try `return calculate(...arguments);`

Answer (score 3):

Your `calculate` function wants separate arguments, but you passed in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)<sup>1</sup>. Using `.apply` spreads the content of the array for you.

<sup>1</sup> Technically an array-like `arguments` object that does not inherit from `Array`.

Comment: Well, technically he passed in the array-like `arguments` object, but close enough. ;)

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but using the word "array" is easier to understand than "array-like `arguments` object" :)

Comment: Marginally easier to understand, but less accurate.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to be pedantic to pre-empt follow up questions about why certain array functions weren't working.

Comment: but why did it use apply.(null..)? what does null represent?

Comment: The first parameter for `.apply` is the value for `this`. It doesn’t have to be `null`.